# How to make this test pass, I'm a bit confused

Tags: ruby

## this is my money class

```
class Money
  def initialize
    @amount = 0
  end

  def amount
    @amount
  end

  def earn(this_many)
    @amount += this_many
  end

  def spend(this_many)
    @amount -= this_many
  end

end
```

## my failing test

```
  def test_cant_spend_money_that_you_dont_have
    money = Money.new
    money.earn(75)
    money.spend(75)
    assert_equal "You can't spend what you don't have", money.spend(12)
    assert_equal 0, money.amount
  end
```

I'm not sure how to modify the amount method to make the test pass... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: my code works until this line...  assert_equal "You can't spend what you don't have", money.spend(12)  this is a test from exercism.io I'm trying to make it pass but I'm stuck... I tried to make a total method but I broke everything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should raise errors when the account doesn't have enough money to spend.

```
class Money
  class InsufficientFunds < StandardError; end

  attr_accessor :amount

  def initialize
    self.amount = 0
  end

  def earn(this_many)
    self.amount += this_many
  end

  def spend(this_many)
    raise InsufficientFunds, "You can't spend what you don't have" if amount < this_many
    self.amount -= this_many
  end

end
```

And your test case should be

```
def test_cant_spend_money_that_you_dont_have
  money = Money.new
  money.earn(75)
  money.spend(75)
  assert_raise Money::InsufficientFunds, "You can't spend what you don't have" do
    money.spend(12)
  end
  assert_equal 0, money.amount
end
```

Comment: thank you!! so much.. i tried something similar but didn't use raise

Comment: In my opinion, a method should never return different types of values (except `nil`). Your `Money#spend` should always return a number, never a string. This is a typical situation using errors.

Comment: Side note the error should probably be abstracted into something like `class InsufficientFunds < StandardError; end` just so that rescuing this error is easier and more explicit throughout the application. Then the test would be  `assert_raise InsufficientFunds {#...}`

Comment: @engineersmnky Agree. Updated my answer.

Comment: The previous update was done in response to a discussion in the question, feel free to roll back if too extreme, @Aetherus.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
assert_equal "You can't spend what you don't have", money.spend(12)
```

to

```
money.spend(12)
assert money.amount > 0, "You can't spend what you don't have"
```

Comment: This does not seem accurate and I am having difficulty following the logic since you have not offered any explanation for your reasoning